# CakePHP 3 implementedEvents() does not fire in emailer

Tags: php, email, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

According to [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/email.html#creating-reusable-emails) , I should be able to add implementedEvents directly to my mailer to seperate all my mailing logic from my codes.

However, when I follow the exact examples in documentation; I see my implemented event function does not work. (not sending emails & does not log anything)

Should I implement my emailer class to somewhere? If so, how should I register my emailer class?

This is my mailer class:

```
<?php
namespace App\Mailer;

use Cake\Mailer\Mailer;
use Cake\Log\Log;


/**
 * Purchase mailer.
 */
class PurchaseMailer extends Mailer
{

    /**
     * Mailer's name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    static public $name = 'Purchase';



    public function implementedEvents()
    {
        return [
            'Model.afterSave' => 'onStatusChange'
        ];
    }

    public function onStatusChange(Event $event, EntityInterface $entity, ArrayObject $options)
    {
        Log::write(
            'info',
            'd1'
        );

        //if ($entity->isNew()) {
            $this->send('sendStatusChangeMails', [$entity]);
        //}
    }


    /**
     * @param  EntityInterface $entity
     * @return [type]
     */
    public function sendStatusChangeMails($entity)
    {
        Log::write(
            'info',
            'd2'
        );
        //if($entity->status_id == 1) {
            //@todo email???
            $this
                    ->template('purchase')
                    ->layout('default')
                    ->emailFormat('html')
                    ->from(['info@example.com' => 'TEST'])
                    ->to('test@test.com')
                    ->subject('test')
                    ->set(['content' => 'this is a purhcase testing mail.']);
        //}
    }


}
```

Comment: You need to add more context, your mailer code is not enough to reproduce the problem. Especially important is the code where you register your mailer/listener.

Comment: well, that is the question. How should I do that? Documentation just says that to separate mail logic from other codes do this and nothing else. How should I register my mailer?

Comment: At that point, the docs seem to expect that you've already read about **[how the event system works](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/events.html#registering-listeners)** A link to the events section might be helpful, you may want to suggest that **[over at GitHub](https://github.com/cakephp/docs/issues)**.

Comment: Thanks! But I still can't understand if mailers are also events or not? I mean, should I register my mailer as an event? and where should I do that? In related entity class?

Answer (score 1):

Answer is the Mailer Class and Events docs.

https://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.Mailer.Mailer.html

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/events.html#registering-listeners

> Our mailer could either be registered in the application bootstrap, or in the Table class' initialize() hook.

So you could subscribe in your mail in your UsersTable initialize:

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $mailer = new UserMailer(); //use App\Mailer\UserMailer;
    $this->eventManager()->on($mailer);

    //more code...
}
```