# Mailer afterSave not sending email in CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, mailer, cakephp-3.4

I'm working in CakePHP 3.4

I have setup Mailer to send verification email to user after registration.

**/src/Mailer/UserMailer.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Mailer;

use Cake\Mailer\Mailer;

class UserMailer extends Mailer
{
    public function verify($user)
    {
        $this
            ->setProfile('no-reply')
            ->setTemplate('register')
            ->setLayout('authentication')
            ->setEmailFormat('html')
            ->setTo($user->email)
            ->setSubject('Verify Account')
            ->setViewVars(['name' => $user->first_name, 'email' => $user->email, 'hash' => $user->verification_hash]);
    }

    public function implementedEvents()
    {
        return [
            'Model.afterSave' => 'onRegistration'
        ];
    }

    public function onRegistration(Event $event, EntityInterface $entity, ArrayObject $options)
    {
        if ($entity->isNew()) {
            $this->send('verify', [$entity]);
        }
    }
}
```

**But, it is not sending any email.**

Emails are being sent when triggered manually from controller using

```
$this->getMailer('User')->send('verify', [$user]);
```

Comment: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36404397/cakephp-3-implementedevents-does-not-fire-in-emailer**

Comment: thanks ndm, can we check if email is sent or not, if it is sent by mailer ?

Comment: Depends on what exactly you mean. In what context/situation?

Answer (score 0):

Please inspect if the `onRegistration` method is even getting fired. I think you have to implement the `Cake\Event\EventListenerInterface`.

See the [docs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/events.html#registering-listeners).

```
use Cake\Event\EventListenerInterface;

class UserMailer extends Mailer implements EventListenerInterface
{
    ...
}
```

**Edit**: Ok, ignore me – just found out the `Mailer` class already listens for events.

https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Mailer.Mailer.html